# Can you scope a Kotlin interface for use with only certain classes?

Tags: java, android, swift, kotlin

I come from primarily an iOS background. In Swift, we can make Protocols which are designed to be implemented by specific classes:

```
protocol MyViewControllerProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func doViewControllerThings()
}
```

This is super powerful because it allows us to extend the protocol with a default implementation and use methods on `self`

```
extension MyViewControllerProtocol {
    func doViewControllerThings() {
        self.view.addSubview(UIView())
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something similar in Kotlin for an Android project. Is this possible?

Comment: Nowadays, you can just say `protocol MyViewControllerProtocol: UIViewController`. 

Comment: Kotlin can't, but Scala can :) `trait MyViewControllerProtocol { self: UIViewController => ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly. You could add a generic property that is intended for the implementer to return itself, but the compiler won't prevent you from providing some other object to satisfy the property.

```
interface SomeInterface {
    val thisRef: Activity

    // ... 
}
```

The above interface can call functions on `thisRef` in its default function implementations.

An implementing class must provide the value for `thisRef`:

```
class MyActivity: Activity(), SomeInterface {
    override val thisRef = this

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can restrict interfaces in this way, but you can restrict functions:

```
interface MyViewController

fun <T> T.doViewControllerThings() where T : UIViewController, T : MyViewController {
    view.addSubview(UIView())
}
```